# Отображение аргументов у Exception

Tags: c#, .net, исключения

Здравствуйте. Есть у меня код обернутый в try catch. Если там вылетает Exception, то логируется вся его информация (stacktrace + message). Но очень не хватает в этих логах значений аргументов, которые были переданные методам. Как мне их получить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никак. Этой информации в исключении нету. Включение её в объект исключения означало бы, например, непредвиденное удлиннение срока жизни объектов, которые вовсе не должны были так долго существовать (например, выделены на стеке). Даже если бы она и была, вам пришлось бы для объекта *любого* типа уметь залогировать его.

Делайте не так. Добавьте логирование в ключевые точки вашей программы, чтобы вы могли видеть, какая функция начала выполняться и какая закончила. Сделав так, вы получите гораздо более важную информацию о том, что же делала программа не только непосредственно в момент возникновения исключения, но и до этого. Для отладки это может быть важно.